# What's the name of PPA? (for ppa-purge)

Tags: ppa, uninstall

I'm testing PPAs, so I commonly use `ppa-purge`, that restores my default versions. But I always have problem with the ppa name. What do I need to put as argument for `ppa-purge`?

I always used my browser to check name on launchpad, but what about when I'm without internet and I can't start X. Org server?

For xorg-edgers I know that `ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa` what about others? Let's say, I know that I have PPA of X-Updates. How do I find out the name of this PPA so I could use with ppa-purge, **without using browser**

So the name should be something like `ppa:NAME/ppa`? How to get this NAME?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This command will list all the PPA repositories you have configured

```
grep ppa /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
```

Alternatively, you can check the repository of a given package

```
apt-cache policy [package-name]
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I still don't get the "string" I need. Line `:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/zeitgeist/ppa/ubuntu lucid main #Zeitgeist PPA` helps me nothing in my case...

Comment: In this case the full repository name can be shortened to `ppa:zeitgeist/ppa`. Hope you see the pattern.

Comment: @AdamByrtek how did you know that?

Comment: Sorry to warm up this 10 years old topic. However, I am stuck at the exactly same situation, I am unable to identify the necessary "PPA name" for ppa-purge. In my case, I want to purge the official winehq stable PPA for Ubuntu 18.04? The original PPA install link was `sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main'` Any help is welcome. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using "Y PPA Manager" which has (among others) one nifty feature: it can list all packages from a ppa enabled on your computer.

Comment: He probably also meant "without using a GUI" since he mentioned xorg-edgers PPA.