# qt4-x11 4.4.7.0 in Lucid

Tags: 10.04, xubuntu, qt, backport

Can this version of QT4 be successfully be installed on Lucid. So many things I try to install depend on this.

**Error: Dependency is not satisfiable: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.7.0~beta1)**

Calibre PPA-Lucid is showing 4:4.7.0-0ubuntu4~ppa2, but notes:

> PACKAGE BUILD FAILURES (STATUS):  -Calibre: It's a problem with qt4, I
>   think, I'm trying a build on my main PPA. Which, if successful, will
>   be copied to this repo.

I've also seen backports available for kubuntu of beta1 and beta2 but I'm running xubuntu and I really don't understand backports anyway.

```
Change Log
Version: *DELETED*  2011-07-24 05:30:54 UTC 
 No changelog for deleted or moved packages. 


Version: 4:4.7.0~beta2-0ubuntu1~lucid1~ppa1     2010-07-11 12:26:25 UTC 

 qt4-x11 (4:4.7.0~beta2-0ubuntu1~lucid1~ppa1) lucid; urgency=low 
 . 
   * Lucid backport 
Source diff to previous version


Version: 4:4.7.0~beta1+git20100522-0ubuntu1~lucid1~ppa1     2010-06-10 00:24:09 UTC 

 qt4-x11 (4:4.7.0~beta1+git20100522-0ubuntu1~lucid1~ppa1) lucid; urgency=low 
 . 
   * Lucid backport
```

Is this a lost cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Backports are**

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports

**Kubuntu Backports**

https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa/+archive/backports:

> PPA description
>
> Backports of new versions of KDE and major KDE apps for Kubuntu which
>   are either too large a change or not yet tested enough to go to Ubuntu
>   Backports.

There is available for the Lucid: qt4-x11 (4:4.7.0-0ubuntu2~lucid1~ppa2).

**Upgrading from a PPA**

> I'm running xubuntu and I really don't understand backports anyway.

You could go to the Kubuntu Backports and click the "Read about installing": https://launchpad.net/+help-soyuz/ppa-sources-list.html. Upgrade will only upgrade the installed packages (Qt).

**Downgrade from the PPA**

A package:

```
:~$ apt-cache show ppa-purge
```

> Description: disables a PPA and reverts to official packages
>
> This program disables a PPA from your Software Sources and reverts your 
>   system back to the official Ubuntu packages. You can use this to
>   return your  system to normal after testing a new version from a PPA.
>
> Homepage: https://launchpad.net/ppa-purge

It is available from the lucid-backports: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=ppa-purge&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all

More:

- [What's the name of PPA? (for ppa-purge)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32835/whats-the-name-of-ppa-for-ppa-purge)
- [How do I remove all packages from a certain repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37531/how-do-i-remove-all-packages-from-a-certain-repository)
- http://bigbrovar.aoizora.org/index.php/2010/01/10/how-to-safely-remove-ppa-repository-from-ubuntu/

Comment: Thank you for the very informative reply. I've added the kubuntu ppa as sugested and upon updating I saw all the qt4 updates ready to be installed but they were grayed out and I was offered an option to do a **"Partial Upgrade"**. After some digging I ran `sudo apt-get --dry-run dist-upgrade` to find only 1 package to be removed. `libqt4-multimedia`  How do I determine what will be affected from this removal. Please advise if this should be a new question.

Comment: It seems that there was changes from the Qt 4.6 to the 4.7. One was the QtMultimedia was replaced by QtMobilities, QtMultimediaKit (by http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1593806 ). After the Lucid the Ubuntu has libqtmultimediakit1 with the Qt 4.7-4.8. If you upgrade to the Qt 4.7 some applications may stop to work - they need the developer attention (new version) to work with the Qt 4.7 or later. Applications that are needing the libqt4-multimedia should have it as a dependency. You should see this with the dry-run/simulation. They will be marked to be removed.