# How to install qt 4.8 from repository?

Tags: installation, qt, qt-creator

How to install qt 4.8 and QtCreator from repository ?

Answer (score 1):

**qt4-x11**

The coming Precise Pagoling is having the Qt 4.8.1, at the moment. The PP will be released: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseSchedule -> April 26th.

**Backported**

The Kubuntu developers ( http://www.kubuntu.org/ )have backported the Qt 4.8 to the Oneiric Ocelot: https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa/+archive/backports .

**PPA**

From the Personal Package Archives for Ubuntu: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=qt4-x11

**Earlier**

[qt4-x11 4.4.7.0 in Lucid](https://askubuntu.com/questions/98150/qt4-x11-4-4-7-0-in-lucid)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find Qt 4.8 in ubuntu official repository.
You should check if the debian package works (I'm not sure it's a good idea to use debian packages, but it might works) : http://packages.debian.org/fr/experimental/libqtcore4

Beside that there is an installer on the official Qt Website (I prefer that solution, seems less risky): http://qt-project.org/downloads