# How to install a lastest version of package?

Tags: upgrade

I have Qt Creator 2.4 installed from package manager, but version 4.8 is out now, and I want to try it. How to properly update to the lastest version, should I download and install it manually?

Comment: There might be a PPA for it somewhere... but you still might be better off compiling from source.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/118878/how-to-install-qt-4-8-from-repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu usually doesn't provide the very latest version of a package because Ubuntu focus on stability. So if you want to install a new version of a program, you can either download the code and compile from source (harder) or just use a PPA (easier).

Assuming you prefer the easier, just search in launchpad the package you want and you probably will find a PPA for what you're looking for. Here's Qtcreator PPA
https://launchpad.net/~alexey-ivanov/+archive/qtcreator

[image: PPA]

To install it, add the lines highlighted in the image
`deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexey-ivanov/qtcreator/ubuntu raring main`
`deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexey-ivanov/qtcreator/ubuntu raring main`

in the end of your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`. Don't forget to change the raring to whether Ubuntu version you're using.