# Reset Amarok version

Tags: 10.04, versions, amarok

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 and I tried Amarok.
It was quite cool, but I wanted to try the latest version so I typed into the console:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

worked so far I got an updated version now. 
But the problem is this version is not very compatible to Ubuntu 10.04 and many features aren't working properly...

How can I change it back?

Answer (score 0):

**Downgrade from the PPA**

```
:~$ apt-cache show ppa-purge
```

> Description: disables a PPA and reverts to official packages
>
> This program disables a PPA from your Software Sources and reverts
>   your system back to the official Ubuntu packages. You can use this to
>   return your system to normal after testing a new version from a PPA.
>
> Homepage: https://launchpad.net/ppa-purge

It is available from the lucid-backports: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=ppa-purge&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all

More:

- http://bigbrovar.aoizora.org/index.php/2010/01/10/how-to-safely-remove-ppa-repository-from-ubuntu/
- [What's the name of PPA? (for ppa-purge)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32835/whats-the-name-of-ppa-for-ppa-purge)
- [How do I remove all packages from a certain repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37531/how-do-i-remove-all-packages-from-a-certain-repository)

Comment: okay, I did that and it said in the last line that something went wrong...But amarok is now the old version.

But FFFFFUUUUU--, I tried to reinstall it, so I deinstalled it and when I hit the Install button it gives me an error which says something like there are some package sources missing or damaged! 

Now I can't install amarok!! Please help!

Comment: Could you add the exact input/output.