# name of a ppa for ppa-purge

Tags: 12.04, apt, ppa

I know that exists the same [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32835/whats-the-name-of-ppa-for-ppa-purge), but I think that in that question there isn't the answer. I have to purge some ppas, and I'm trying to use `ppa-purge` with this command:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:<ppa_name>/ppa
```

But what is the `ppa_name`?? I have this (bad)  sources.list.d

```
danielrichter2007-grub-customizer-precise.list       google-chrome.list.save                      n-muench-vlc-precise.list                 videolan-stable-daily-precise.list.save
danielrichter2007-grub-customizer-precise.list.save  jockey.list                                  n-muench-vlc-precise.list.save            webupd8team-unstable-precise.list
dropbox.list                                         jockey.list.save                             relan-exfat-precise.list                  webupd8team-unstable-precise.list.save
dropbox.list.save                                    langdalepl-gvfs-mtp-precise.list             relan-exfat-precise.list.save             wine-wine-builds-precise.list
freefilesync-ffs-precise.list                        langdalepl-gvfs-mtp-precise.list.save        thefanclub-grive-tools-precise.list       wine-wine-builds-precise.list.save
freefilesync-ffs-precise.list.save                   lubuntu-dev-lubuntu-daily-precise.list       thefanclub-grive-tools-precise.list.save
google-chrome.list                                   lubuntu-dev-lubuntu-daily-precise.list.save  videolan-stable-daily-precise.list
```

But I don't know the name, for example:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:lubuntu/ppa
Updating packages lists
PPA to be removed: lubuntu ppa
Warning:  Could not find package list for PPA: lubuntu ppa
```

**Edit**

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ grep ppa /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu precise main
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu precise main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/danielrichter2007-grub-customizer-precise.list:# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu precise main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/danielrichter2007-grub-customizer-precise.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu precise main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/danielrichter2007-grub-customizer-precise.list.save:# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu precise main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/danielrichter2007-grub-customizer-precise.list.save:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu precise main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/freefilesync-ffs-precise.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/freefilesync/ffs/ubuntu precise main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/freefilesync-ffs-precise.list:deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/freefilesync/ffs/ubuntu precise main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/freefilesync-ffs-precise.list.save:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/freefilesync/ffs/ubuntu precise main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/freefilesync-ffs-precise.list.save:deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/freefilesync/ffs/ubuntu precise main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/langdalepl-gvfs-mtp-precise.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/langdalepl/gvfs-mtp/ubuntu precise main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/langdalepl-gvfs-mtp-precise.list:deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/langdalepl/gvfs-mtp/ubuntu precise main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/langdalepl-gvfs-mtp-precise.list.save:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/langdalepl/gvfs-mtp/ubuntu precise main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/langdalepl-gvfs-mtp-precise.list.save:deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/langdalepl/gvfs-mtp/ubuntu precise main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/lubuntu-dev-lubuntu-daily-precise.list.save:deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/lubuntu-dev/lubuntu-daily/ubuntu precise main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/n-muench-vlc-precise.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/n-muench/vlc/ubuntu precise main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/n-muench-vlc-precise.list:deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/n-muench/vlc/ubuntu precise main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/n-muench-vlc-precise.list.save:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/n-muench/vlc/ubuntu precise main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/n-muench-vlc-precise.list.save:deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/n-muench/vlc/ubuntu precise main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/relan-exfat-precise.list:# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/relan/exfat/ubuntu precise main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/relan-exfat-precise.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/relan/exfat/ubuntu precise main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/relan-exfat-precise.list.save:# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/relan/exfat/ubuntu precise main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/relan-exfat-precise.list.save:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/relan/exfat/ubuntu precise main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/thefanclub-grive-tools-precise.list:# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/grive-tools/ubuntu precise main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/thefanclub-grive-tools-precise.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/grive-tools/ubuntu precise main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/thefanclub-grive-tools-precise.list.save:# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/grive-tools/ubuntu precise main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/thefanclub-grive-tools-precise.list.save:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/grive-tools/ubuntu precise main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/videolan-stable-daily-precise.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/stable-daily/ubuntu precise main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/videolan-stable-daily-precise.list:deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/stable-daily/ubuntu precise main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/videolan-stable-daily-precise.list.save:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/stable-daily/ubuntu precise main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/videolan-stable-daily-precise.list.save:deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/stable-daily/ubuntu precise main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-unstable-precise.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/unstable/ubuntu precise main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-unstable-precise.list:deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/unstable/ubuntu precise main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-unstable-precise.list.save:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/unstable/ubuntu precise main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-unstable-precise.list.save:deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/unstable/ubuntu precise main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine-wine-builds-precise.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/wine/wine-builds/ubuntu precise main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine-wine-builds-precise.list:deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/wine/wine-builds/ubuntu precise main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine-wine-builds-precise.list.save:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/wine/wine-builds/ubuntu precise main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine-wine-builds-precise.list.save:deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/wine/wine-builds/ubuntu precise main
```

Comment: You need to see what is in these lists for ppa url.

Comment: You need to type this: sudo apt-get purge ppa nameofit

Comment: @Pilot6 edited my question. Michael the command doesn't work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to look into the list files. It many distributions it is found under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`.

For instance, I have a java ppa. The list is `webupd8team-java-trusty.list`.

It contains:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main
```

So the `ppa-purge` command will look this way:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:webupd8team/java
```

For your "lubuntu" ppa the command is:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:lubuntu-dev/lubuntu-daily
```

The `<ppa-name>` is after `http://ppa.launchpad.net/` and before the distro name.

If you still get errors, then your list is damaged. You can always add a PPA then purge it, e.g.:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lubuntu-dev/lubuntu-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo ppa-purge ppa:lubuntu-dev/lubuntu-daily
```

Comment: the error persists:
`sudo ppa-purge ppa:lubuntu-dev/lubuntu-daily
Updating packages lists
PPA to be removed: lubuntu-dev lubuntu-daily
Warning:  Could not find package list for PPA: lubuntu-dev lubuntu-daily`

Comment: It works for me on that ppa. I added it and purged.

Comment: In your case you do not have `lubuntu-dev-lubuntu-daily-precise.list` in the last output. Did you delete it after the first one? Try another ppa, or re-add that ppa.

Comment: for some ppa works, but not for all

Comment: You probably manually deleted some lists.

Comment: The ppas that doesn't work are in the folder sources.list.d

Comment: You do not have now `lubuntu-dev-lubuntu-daily-precise.list`. But you had it before. Now you have only `lubuntu-dev-lubuntu-daily-precise.list.save`. You can add the ppa again, run `sudo apt-get update` and purge it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35307/discussion-between-linofex-and-pilot6).

Comment: The main problem is the error "Warning:  Could not find package list for PPA: etc" because `apt`  don't run Linux upgrade if some PPA there. Se my comment at https://askubuntu.com/a/1191390/439867