# How to upgrade Ubuntu 16 LTS to 18 LTS after purge-ppa crash

Tags: upgrade

During automatic Ubuntu's graphic interface upgrade, it solicitated to do `purge-ppa`, to purge PPA's... And I do it... But during `ppa-purge`s an error arrives, and now, even on terminal running the command **`sudo apt upgrade`**, it  say:

```
The following packages have mismatched dependencies:
  libelementary2: It depends: libefreet-bin
                   It depends: libethumb-client-bin
  terminology: It depends: libefreet-bin
                It depends: libethumb-client-bin
E: Mismatched dependencies. Try using -f.
```

---

As suggested I try also `apt-get -f install` but

```
sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  dctrl-tools libcgal11v5 libcoin80v5 libiso9660-8 libmcrypt4 libmpcdec6 libopenscenegraph100v5 libopenthreads20 libpcre2-8-0 libpgm-5.2-0
  libvcdinfo0 libxine2 libxine2-bin libxine2-doc libxine2-ffmpeg libxine2-misc-plugins libxine2-plugins snapd-login-service xml2
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libefreet-bin libethumb-client-bin
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libefreet-bin libethumb-client-bin
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
26 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/31.3 kB of archives.
After this operation, 137 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 289060 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libefreet-bin_1.8.6-2.5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libefreet-bin (1.8.6-2.5) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libefreet-bin_1.8.6-2.5_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/efreetd', which is also in package libefl-bin 201702271931-50218~ubuntu16.04.1
Preparing to unpack .../libethumb-client-bin_1.8.6-2.5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libethumb-client-bin (1.8.6-2.5) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libethumb-client-bin_1.8.6-2.5_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/ethumbd', which is also in package libefl-bin 201702271931-50218~ubuntu16.04.1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libefreet-bin_1.8.6-2.5_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libethumb-client-bin_1.8.6-2.5_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

---

Purges that I do, some of the last ones proceded the error:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:mkusb/unstable
sudo ppa-purge ppa:webupd8team/atom
sudo ppa-purge ppa:ondrej/php

sudo ppa-purge ppa:git-core/ppa
sudo ppa-purge ppa:enlightenment-git/ppa
sudo ppa-purge ppa:smathot/cogscinl
sudo ppa-purge ppa:mkusb/ppa
sudo ppa-purge ppa:gezakovacs/ppa
sudo ppa-purge ppa:mc3man/avidemux1
```

Comment: Generally speaking, it's always a bad idea to upgrade a heavily customized system, as so many thing can go wrong. I would backup important files and reinstall.

Comment: A re-install using 'something else' (or 'Manual Partitioning') is always an option.  Select your current partitions and do **not** format, it will note your installed packaged, erase system directories, install normally, add back packages (if available in repos) without touching data files (unless in system directories or you have 'format' selected).  Backup first of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your particular case I'll recommend to force package installation with

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-all /var/cache/apt/archives/libefreet-bin_1.8.6-2.5_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i --force-all /var/cache/apt/archives/libethumb-client-bin_1.8.6-2.5_amd64.deb
```

and then resume with:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

and finally install newest dependencies with

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Hi Norbert, there are some place more to delete? now  ppa-purge say "Warning:  Could not find package list for PPA: etc", see also this open-question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55468708/why-add-apt-repository-remove-doesnt-remove-the-ppa-list

Comment: Similar *old Ubuntu bug* discussed at https://askubuntu.com/a/729745/439867